# Need help in looking for the extremum point of the trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to look for the the extremum point of the trigonometric function.
It's a problem about wireless communication.There are three signal sources and one receiver.$t_1,t_2,t_3$ means arrival time from signal sources to receiver.I have got frequency domain impulse response.Amplitude of the impulse response in the frequency domain is $|h(f)|=K|\frac{1}{t_1^4}e^{-j2\pi ft_1}+\frac{1}{t_2^4}e^{-j2\pi ft_2}+\frac{1}{t_3^4}e^{-j2\pi ft_3}|$,K is constant,$|.|$means amplitude.I want to use $h(f)$ to calculate $t_1,t_2,t_3$.Using the real and imaginary parts to calculate amplitude of $h_1(f)$
$$
h_1(f)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{t_1^8}+\frac{1}{t_2^8}+\frac{1}{t_3^8}+\frac{2}{t_1^4t_2^4}(cos2\pi ft_1cos2\pi ft_2+sin2\pi ft_1sin 2\pi ft_2)+\frac{2}{t_1^4t_3^4}(cos2\pi ft_1cos2\pi ft_3+sin2\pi ft_1sin 2\pi ft_3)+\frac{2}{t_2^4t_3^4}(cos2\pi ft_2cos2\pi ft_3+sin2\pi ft_2sin 2\pi ft_3)}
$$
where $t_1$,$t_2$,$t_3$ are constant,f is the variable.I want to know when the function takes the extremum,f=?
[image: The image of h_1(f)]

$$ h_2(f) = \frac{1}{t_1^8}+\frac{1}{t_2^8}+\frac{1}{t_3^8}+\frac{2}{t_1^4t_2^4}cos2\pi f(t_1-t_2)+\frac{2}{t_1^4t_3^4}cos2\pi f(t_1-t_3)+\frac{2}{t_2^4t_3^4}cos2\pi f(t_2-t_3)
$$
Take the derivative of the function $h_1(f)$
$$ h_3(f) = -\frac{4\pi(t_1-t_2)}{t_1^4t_2^4}sin2\pi f(t_1-t_2)-\frac{4\pi(t_1-t_3)}{t_1^4t_3^4}sin2\pi f(t_1-t_3)-\frac{4\pi(t_2-t_3)}{t_2^4t_3^4}sin2\pi f(t_2-t_3)
$$
How to solve $h_3(f)=0$?

Comment: First simplify your expressions $\cos a \cos b+ \sin a \sin b$ into $\cos(a-b).$ Then you can suppress the big square root because finding the extrema of $f(x)$ amounts to find the extrema of $f(x)^2$.

Comment: I have simplify the expressions,but i have no idea about how to solve $h_2(f)=0$

Comment: Hopefuly no closed form solution can be awaited. But are you looking for approximate solutions ?

Comment: $t_1,t_2,t_3 $are unknown,i want to find all of the solutions in one period.

Comment: If i want to get approximate solutions,how? FFT will help ?

Comment: I don't see how the FFT could help. Could you say something about the origin of the problem (polyphase electrical engineering ?)

Comment: Did I describe it clearly?

Comment: Yes, it is clearer when coming back to the initial complex form. I am presently attempting to understand with a geometrical representation the influences of the parameters. I will present you what I have obtained in the coming hours.

Comment: What are the typical ranges of values for $t_1,t_2,t_3$ ?

Comment: 10ns - 30ns.It's a problem about wireless optical communication,the typical distances between singal sources and recevier are 3m-10m,so the typical ranges of values for t1,t2,t3 are 10ns - 30ns.

Comment: I begin to understand : if $t_1,t_2,t_3$ are non-commensurable, (I mean by that they have no common multiple), you can have an infinite variety of peaks with in particular values of the peaks arbitrarily close to $K(1/t_1^4 +1/t_2^4 +1/t_3^4 )$. I would be tempted to speak in terms of signal's "envelope"...

Answer (score 1):

Not a full-fleshed answer but a way to narrow up the solutions.

I will work on the complex representation of:

$$\varphi(f)=\underbrace{R_1e^{-j2\pi ft_1}}_{\vec{OP_1}}+\underbrace{R_2e^{-j2\pi ft_2}}_{\vec{P_1P_2}}+\underbrace{R_3e^{-j2\pi ft_3}}_{\vec{P_2P_3}}$$

with:

$$R_1:=\frac{1}{t_1^4}, \ \ R_2:=\frac{1}{t_2^4}, \ \ R_3:=\frac{1}{t_3^4}$$

and points $P_k$ as in the figure below.

We assume (without loss of generality) that:

$$t_1 \ge t_2 \ge t_3 \ \ \iff \ \ R_1 \le R_2 \le R_3$$

Imagine it as planetary representation, as if  the Sun in $O$, the Earth orbiting around it with center in $P_1$ (black circle), the Moon's center in $P_2$ (red circle), a satellite orbiting around the Moon in $P_3$ (blue circle).

[image]

The two dotted circles are the limits of "exclusion areas" with resp. radii :

$$R_{max}=R_1 + R_2 + R_3 \ \ \text{and} \ \ R_{min}=R_1 - (R_2 + R_3)$$

at least in the case where $R_1 \ge R_2 + R_3$ in which you look to be, considering your graphical representation.

As $R_{max}$ and $R_{min}$ are accessible to observation (in terms of the signal's envelope, we have two equations for the 3 unknowns $t_1, t_2, t_3$, from which it is hopefuly possible to deduce in a second step further estimations...

Comment: A very interesting connected text [here](https://blog.wolfram.com/2018/04/24/a-tale-of-three-cosines-an-experimental-mathematics-adventure/)

Comment: It's helpful.Do you mean $|h(f)_{max }|=R_1+R_2 +R_3$,$|h(f)_{min }|=R_1-R_2 -R_3$.The connected text is interesting,I need some time to understand it.

Comment: Yes, it's what I mean. Happy you find my half-answer helpful.